# Cursor disappears in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition my cursor frequently disappears when I perform the `Ctrl+.` shortcut to resolve missing dependencies. For example, if I am creating a new Entity Framework entity and want to add the `[Required]` attribute to one of my properties:

1. Type `[Required]`. The attribute gets a red squiggly underline.
2. Click `Ctrl+.` to bring up the suggested imports
3. Select the `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` option using the arrow keys
4. Press `Enter` to select it and import the `using` statement

Sometimes I can continue coding without any issues. But most of the time my cursor disappears and I have to click back on the code editor to get my cursor back.

It happens to me on several different computers using Windows 7, Windows 8.1, or Windows 10. I've tried resetting my VS2015 configurations to default, but it didn't seem to help. The only other thing I can think of that might be worth mentioning is that I'm use the Dark theme.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a setting change so that the editor keeps focus, or a keyboard shortcut to get the cursor back? It isn't the end of the world to use the mouse but I never had to do it in 2013 so it is slightly annoying.

Comment: On me VS often cause cursor to change into a "fir tree", sorry not sure how to describe it better. What is most annoying is that it changes cursor for all desktop apps, not only for itself, so the only way to get the normal cursor back is restart VS. Note, I was not able to find out what triggers the cursor change.

Comment: I've also run in to this problem which has lead me to this question. I'd LOVE to know the answer to this because it drives me crazy!

Comment: @jzm Did you guys find any solution to this problem ? I am now in the same situation. Please help.This really drives me crazy too.

Comment: @katmanco - TBH, I haven't noticed it much anymore. Either they fixed it in one of the updates, or I've gotten used to it and just click out of habit :)

Comment: Thanks for reply and I will update my VS2015 and write back here to let you know  .

Comment: If you ctrl+tab to another file tab, then back again, it'll bring back your cursor, but that's still irritating. At least your hands don't have to leave the keyboard though.

Comment: ctrl-tab doesn't work, this problem is still ongoing a year later

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and found that if I went to my mouse properties and changed the default pointer for Text Select to one with white in it, I didn't lose the pointer in the editor.  I don't know if this'll solve your issue, but it helped with mine.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem as well, for me it seemed to be a glitch with the touch screen capabilities on my laptop. The cursor would disappear when using the track pad and moving into the work area in VS, and come back when I moved it outside to like solution explorer or similar.

Easily resolved by tapping the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the missing cursor issue in VS 2015 Community Edition and it turns out the culprit was the Gotomeeting client software running on my desktop. I was accessing VS 2015 in an RDP session and as long as Gotomeeting was running on the desktop running the RDP client my VS 2015 cursor in the RDP session would disappear randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that the blinking cursor completely disappeared in Visual Studio 2017 (and probably other places as well). Found this old block post, that helped me:

> I found the cause of the problem.  I had also noticed that I did not have a text cursor (caret) in programs like Windows Live Mail.  Somehow my caret size got changed to zero.  The solution in Windows 7 was to go to Control Panel, Ease of Access Center, Make the computer easier to see, and under Make things on the screen easier to see set the thickness of the blinking cursor to 1 (mine was displaying a blank field).  After applying the change, the text cursor displayed fine in Visual Studio Editor and Windows Live Mail.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c7ba185e-1840-4649-984e-c12d5525baa2/cursor-not-visible-in-visual-studio-editor?forum=vseditor

Answer (score 0):

None of the (many across web) posted solutions for the disappearing cursor worked.  I found a solution that works for me go to:

`Tools/Options/Environment/General/Window layout`

there are 2 radio buttons:

- Tabbed Documents
- Multiple Documents

You must select one or the other.  I switched to `Multiple Documents` and this solved the problem.

**Details**:  this problem manifests when changing the focus to any other open **window/application** via `Alt+Tab`. On return, Vis Studio has no cursor visible.  `Ctrl+Tab` is a sorry workaround, yet effective.  But this fix is totally sat for me.

Comment: Thank you Kaveh for your kind edit/improvement to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing the "insert" button. You might need to hold down the "fn" key for this.